# Naming C++ Variables

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++.

MY question is, is this a valid variable name?

```
int @variableName
```

I want to include the '@' symbol.

Thank you.

Comment: What resources are you using to learn C++ from that don't tell you about valid variable names? If you want a good book on C++, search StackOverflow, I'm sure there are lots of recommendations.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not a valid variable name. C++ only allows letters, digits and the underscore character, and the variable name cannot start with a digit.

Comment: C++ also allows "*universal-character-names*" that do not fall in the ranges of `0x0`-`0x20` and `0x7F`-`0x9F`, inclusive. Though I confess I've never seen it done and don't know if my compiler supports it. :)

Answer (score 3):

No. In C++, and most languages, the only valid characters in variable names are a-z,A-Z, 0-9, and _. (And cannot start with a number).

```
int variableName; //fine
int _variable //fine
int 8variable //not fine
int @variable //not fine
```

Comment: careful of reserved identifiers.

Comment: The second one is only fine in certain contexts.